# Why is there no force between a current loop and an open loop

Tags: electromagnetism

This is a question about figure 2 in [this article](http://www.alternativephysics.org/book/Magnetism.htm).

[image: Open and closed]

Why there will be no force between the wires despite of having a relative velocity between electrons in the two wires?

Comment: Moving charged particules create a magnetic field that acts on moving charged particules.

Comment: @TZDZ: I think you didn't read the original article. Please read it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why there will be no force between the wires despite of having a
>   relative velocity between electrons in the two wires?

The succinct answer is that the open wire is electrically neutral.

It's true that there is relative motion between the (mobile) electrons in the two wires so there is indeed a magnetic force between them (in a frame in which electrons in both wires are moving).

[image]

It's also true that there is the same relative motion between the mobile electrons of the rightmost circuit and the positive nuclei of the left-most circuit so there is also a magnetic force between them.  However, due to the opposite sign of charge, *this magnetic force is in the opposite direction*.

Since the wires are electrically neutral, there is no *net* magnetic force.

Comment: One wire (right side in the diagram) is carrying current.

Comment: @Subhra, that fact is understood and incorporated in my answer.